# Jquery Datatable not loading in remotePC after hosting to local IIS

Tags: jquery, web-services, datatables

I am using a jquery **data table** it's working nicely in local PC,
I hosted the application in local PC ,and used the hosted link it worked in my local PC .
When i checked the hosted link in other PC  **data table** is  not loading .

Note:Data table is loading from a webservice method

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'data.asmx/GetPrograms',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#datatable').DataTable({
                        data: data,
                        columns: [
                    { 'data': 'PROGRAM_NAME',

                        'render': function (PROGRAM_NAME) {
                            return '<a href="">' + PROGRAM_NAME + ' </a>';

                        }


                    },
                    { 'data': 'PROGRAM_OWNER' },
                    { 'data': 'PROGRAM_DESC' },
                    { 'data': 'PROGRAM_PC' },
                    { 'data': 'Oper' },
                    { 'data': 'fusion' },



                    ]

                    })




                }



            })







    });
```

Thanks
In Advance

Comment: You are getting any console errors in other PC?

Comment: No its showing the header of the table  as in html i have added .not the data.

Comment: Did you check browser console? Check the network tab too in browser console..

Comment: I am getting a syntax error there .                                                                  Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetPrograms'.                      I am very new to jQuery could you Please check

Comment: Did you host your service too in the same server? The URL is not proper its saying.. Try to give absolute url..

Comment: So what was the issue?

Comment: In web .config i added the configuration

Comment: Cool.. Post it as answer with some coding and accept it by yourself.. Happy coding.. :)